ChatGPT API request with type:image_url — error while downloading, invalid_image_url
I am sending a request to the ChatGPT API with the following content:
        'model' => 'gpt-4o',
        'messages' => [
            [
                'role' => 'user',
                'content' => array_merge(
                [
                    [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'text' => $prompt
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'type' => 'image_url',
                    'image_url' => [
                         'url' => $image_url
                    ]
                ]
                )
            ]
        ],
        'max_tokens' => 300
    ]);

My task is to define the contents of an image in a few words. And this task is performed perfectly, without problems. But the problem is in cases where at least 1 image is not available. In this case, I get an error:

I want to upload multiple images at once, but if at least 1 image fails to upload, the entire API response becomes an error. I need to get a separate result for inaccessible images so that all other images will continue to be processed. How can I do this? I have already tried editing the prompt and asking to report an error. Uploading images one at a time is an extreme solution, I would like all of them together.

You should make sure all required data are uploaded without problems, so the API can respond properly. Can you please share your code?

@Erfan I understand that checking the URL availability before sending a request to ChatGPT is a good solution. But I would like to find out first if there is an opportunity to transfer this check to the ChatGPT side.
Unfortunately, I can't share all the code. I need to solve the problem at the logic level, we will write the code ourselves.

I'm not sure about the idea of checking URL availability by ChatGPT. However, it seems that doing this would result in your current problem.
